# Can I have a public APEX REST API?

Tags: rest-api

Can I have a public APEX REST API e.g. APEX REST api that is accessible without authentication?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes you can. You will need to configure a public site and make the webservice available through it. There is an excellent tip on the [developerforce blogs](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2012/02/quick-tip-public-restful-web-services-on-force-com-sites.html) explaining it in more detail.

I implemented this a few months ago and ran into some issues, but did get it running :). The biggest of which is that your request must have the proper Content-Type Salesforce restful webservices reject `x-www-form-urlencoded` and refactoring the legacy system was a bit of a problem.

Comment: which content-type should I use if I want to get back a JSON response?

Comment: You will get a JSON response back by default. If necessary, you can force the issue via the `Accept: application/json` HTTP header or by appending `.json` to the URL.