# servlet logic with Apex

Tags: apex, webservices

I want to implement for the below flow.

I do post http request to the another end point url.

that end point system will do http posting to the return url that I have specified for more information.

In that case, **How can I set up or make a Apex class which can process the http post from other system?**

So that I can capture the information from the http post and proceess the necessary things.

In java, we can create servlet and get the information back to our system.

As I am new to Apex, **how can I make the url that can be exposed to other system and allow to capture information from post request by other system?**

any reference will be so helpful for me.

IMPORTANT NOTE: No authentication should be needed. As I just want to get the result of other system.

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expose a `REST` service in Apex to which a remote system can `POST`.

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST

I believe you can even do that without autorization, but I am not sure if you really want to do that ..

Comment: I'm not sure that you can do it without authentication of some kind, I've always had to specify a session ID in the header. And as you say, I'm not sure that you would want to accept unauthenticated requests...

Comment: The Apex rest service can be public: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4713/can-i-have-a-public-apex-rest-api