# Create accounts from URL ping

Tags: soap-api

I have an external form (in a website) from office autopilot that once submitted, it saved the data to a specific list. OAP allows me to ping url, from salesforce how can I create the url to be pointed? Or if I decide to go the other way, how  can I from salesforce do the trigger that send the information to OAP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to go with custom code. Take a look at [REST services](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_rest_code_sample_basic.htm). In the link, you'd need to have a session Id established with Salesforce. If you want to make it public, take a look at this [SE answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4713/can-i-have-a-public-apex-rest-api).

You may also want to look at creating the form on a public Salesforce Site so you don't even have to worry about the integration between the two systems.