# Setting up a Public REST API

Tags: rest-api, force.com-sites

I found a different question asking, "[Can I have a public APEX REST API?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4713/can-i-have-a-public-apex-rest-api)" which led to a [blog post](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/02/quick-tip-public-restful-web-services-on-force-com-sites.html) explaining how to setup a public site to expose a REST API:

1. Create your REST API in Apex as normal
2. Create a public site
3. Configure the public user to have access to the Apex class and any other sObjects

I followed the directions and have a publicly available site, but when I do a GET to the URL the site returns a HTTP 503 error page. My understanding is that shouldn't even be routed through the VF handler.

Webservice code:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/helloWorld/*')
global class RestWebservice {

  @HttpGet
  global static String helloWorld(){
    return 'HelloWorld';
  }

}
```

URL being queried: `https://chale1-developer-edition.na14.force.com/services/apexrest/helloWorld`

I have tried:

- Turning on debug logs for the public site user, but that didn't help as no logs recorded the error.
- Verified no redirects are configured
- With and without a header for `Accept: application/json`
- Tried on two different dev orgs, on different instances

Answers to questions:

- I have not built any apps in this org, nor are there any installed packages, so there are no namespaces
- Trying /services/apexrest/helloWord/blah returned the same response
- Most of the raw response is just HTML. The headers have content-type of text/html, X-Powered-By: Salesforce.com ApexPages, P3P: CP="CUR OTR STA", cache-control, and nothing else of note

Eventually I would like to have a webhook use this API which is why it needs to be public. What else could cause the service to return a 503?

Comment: Can you inspect the raw response for an error? Also append `/something` to the service endpoint?

Comment: do you happen to have a namespace on that org? (managed package)

Comment: Questions answered and I filled in the URL just in case somebody wants to see the actual response.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are using the wrong URL I think

Try this:
https://chale1-developer-edition.na14.force.com/**test**/services/apexrest/helloWorld

EDIT - When I looked at the HTML that came back original URL in Postman, I saw this message:

```
https://chale1-developer-edition.na14.force.com/test</i> is down for maintenance
```

So I realized he must have used added a suffix to the Default Web Address in the Site called test. The REST URL includes the default suffix as part of the full URL, so I added that the URL he provided, and it worked...

Comment: Wow, that worked! Where did you get that from?

Comment: could you please explain why "test" should be needed? In the related article the service url shown has not the *test* you are refering

Comment: 'test' is only needed because he added a suffix to the Default Web Address - if you just create a site and leave that blank, the URL would be as described in the article

Comment: That's the name of my site and the default page I configured; I'll try removing those.

Comment: OK, I removed the default page and that fixed it as well. Thank you!

Comment: Ah - it was **almost** namespaces :-)

Comment: Haha thinking the same thing, Pat! @metadaddy

Comment: This saved my day today. Thank you

Comment: doesn't work now? in 2024 in the new public site URLs?

Comment: Apex REST via a Public Guest site definitely still works in 2024, if that's what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a managed package & your namespace name is '**devns**' then try to add

> /services/apexrest/**devns**/helloWorld