# Apex Rest API Public Web Service Cannot See Data?

Tags: apex, rest

I saw how to implement public REST API with Salesforce,

[Can I have a public APEX REST API?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4713/can-i-have-a-public-apex-rest-api)

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/02/quick-tip-public-restful-web-services-on-force-com-sites.html

The problem is that when i want to expose data, i run soql on Contact object and i did not retrieve any data!

As I see in this documentation: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_rest_exposing_data.htm the it is run as a system context and i should retrieve data :(

Did someone suceed to expose Data from object in a public rest webservice? what I should do in the Site exposing the rest web service?

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/getmenu/*')

global with sharing class MenuService {



   @HttpGet
 global static String getMenuTree() {
    RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
    res.addHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.addHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    String contactId = RestContext.request.params.get('contactid'); 

    JSONGenerator generator = JSON.createGenerator(true);
    generator.writeStartObject();
    if(contactId!=null && (contactId.length() == 15 || contactId.length() == 18) && Pattern.matches('^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$', contactId)) {
        Contact[] contacts = [Select Id,Name from Contact where Id=:contactId];
        if(contacts.size()>0){
             generator.writeStringField('Name',contacts[0].name);
        }else{
            generator.writeStringField('Name','Unknow contact');
        }
    }
    //... other logic

    generator.writeEndObject();

    return generator.getAsString();
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please post your code. I think problem in code signature or modification.

With sharing modificator used for apply current sharing model to you class.
You can read docs about it - https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm

Comment: I added a part of the code

Comment: Try to remove with sharing modificator

Comment: That solved my problem! can you explain why? and then edit your original post?